# Trigger function when a variable has a certain value

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I have a UIScrollView and I want to trigger a function whenever the content offset is equal to a certain value.

I tried

```
var defaultOffset: CGPoint = ...

func checkScroll() {
    for i = 1; i > 0; i {
        if ScrollView.contentOffset.x == defaultOffset.x {
            functionToTrigger()
            i = 0
        }
    }
}
```

but that doesn't work.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked out: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll: - Maybe putting something like what you have into that delegate method will give you what you want

Answer (score 3):

I would you recommend a different approach.
Set this class as the `UIScrollViewDelegate`.
Then just use `scrollViewDidScroll` method to compute your value, like so:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x == defaultOffset.x {
        functionToTrigger()
    }
}
```

Comment: That would make sense but I can't override scrollViewDidScroll() and when I launch the app and scroll that method never gets executed for some reason

Comment: Are you overriding in a subclass of UIScrollViewDelegate?

Comment: I think would be nice if you could share more code or information then. I'm not following what's going wrong.